# Передача информации на страницу

Tags: php

Есть главная страница, и второстепенная
Можно ли при переходе по ссылке с главной на второстепенную передать какую-либо информацию на второстепенную страницу?

Comment: Да, можно - передавая необходимые параметры в виде get-запроса.

Comment: Можно и POST и GET запросом. GET запросом вы добавите параметры к адресу страницы (самый простой вариант). А POST запросом вам придётся либо через форму отправлять, либо через JavaScript обработчик (сложнее, но адрес не меняется).

Comment: @Rootware как говорят у нас на сайте "ответы в ответы": не стоит писать в комментарии то, что правильнее было бы оформить ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Информацию между страницами можно передавать как POST, так и GET запросом.

**GET** - запрос все параметры содержит в адресной строке. Это самый простой вариант.

**POST** - запрос вам придётся либо через форму отправлять дополнительные параметры, либо через JavaScript обработчик. В этом случае адрес остаётся неизменным, но реализация гораздо сложнее, в зависимости от выбора реализации. Использование тега `<form/>` из них самый простой. При этом ссылка может быть не только кнопкой, но и обычной ссылкой. Тут больше зависит от вашей фантазии и знаний JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать данные серез сессию. 
Стартуешь сессию session_start(). Далее просто добавляешь в массив $_SESSION.
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php